# Field characteristic for a finite product of fields of characteristic $0$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Kind of a silly question, but is a finite product of fields of characteristic $0$ also of characteristic $0$? For instance, $\mathbb{C}$ has characteristic $0$, but then does $\mathbb{C}^n, n>1$ also have characteristic $0$?

Comment: Consider the element $(1,0)\in\mathbb C^2$. What additive multiple of this element equals the neutral element of $\mathbb C^2$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $k$ be a field. The multiplicative identity of $k^n$ is $(1,\ldots,1)$.
Therefore, for all $m > 0$,
$$m(1,\ldots,1)=(m\cdot 1,\ldots,m\cdot 1) \ne (0,\ldots,0),$$ since $m \cdot 1 \ne 0$ in $k$. Thus $k^n$ has characteristic $0$.

**Alternatively** (but actually the same, just more abstractly): Note that the injective homomorphism of rings $\mathbb Z \to k$ factors through $\mathbb Z \xrightarrow{\alpha} k^n \xrightarrow{\beta} k$, where $\alpha(1) = (1,\ldots,1)$ and $\beta(\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n) = \lambda_1$. Since $\beta\circ \alpha$ is injective, so must be $\alpha$.

Answer (score 3):

More generally, if $A,B$ are two rings then $\operatorname{char}(A\oplus B)=\operatorname{lcm}(\operatorname{char}(A),\operatorname{char}(B))$. Indeed, if $k\in\Bbb Z$ then $k\cdot (a,b)=(0,0)$ for all $(a,b)\in A\oplus B$ iff $ka=0$ for all $a\in A$ and $kb=0$ for all $b\in B$.
In particular for any (ring or) field $F$ and $n\ge1$, $F^n$ is a ring of same characteristic.

Note that we need to use the definition of characteristic that is applicable to non-unitary rings here.